# using List to delete elements from middle, first position and last position in sequence

Tags: coldfusion

trying to handle the list deletion but stuck on ts deletion process: here is my small gist which i am working on, any help appreciated

> https://trycf.com/gist/aa3871e76db36ad446b770b9bbbb4cec/lucee5?theme=monokai

```
<cfset lstFirst = "1,2,3,4,5">

<cfset lstMiddle = "6,7,8,9,10">

<cfset lstLast = "11,12,13,14,15">
```

From the lstFirst I should be able to delete from reverse like `5,4,3,2,1` but i should not be able to 
delete from middle of the very next item which is `2`

From the lstMiddle if the middle one is 8, i should be able to delete `7,6` and so on or `9,10` but i should not be able to 
delete `6,10` without deleting `7` and `9`

From the lstLast which is complete reverse of the lstFirst where the last element is selected and i should be able to delete 
from `14,13,12` onward but cannot delete from middle or from 11 onward, it must start its deletion from `14` or `15` backwards this is the way i am trying to make it work

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Slow down and say what the heck you are trying to do here.

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment...

Comment: @Miguel-F not exactly, if that needs a name, you can say that but i am stuck on this and i need some help on it

Comment: @Jabbu - Well if it's homework, having someone else write the code for you doesn't do you any favors ;-)  Either way, I don't really understand the question ..  despite reading it a few times. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I only made that comment because I cannot think of any practical example where something like that would be necessary. Regardless, I too am having trouble understanding your question. Please clarify your question and add some more detail so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
**<cfoutput>
    <cfset lstFirst = "1,2,3,4,5">
    <cfset lstMiddle = "6,7,8,9,10">
    <cfset lstLast = "11,12,13,14,15">

    <!--- It's work all dynamic values for lstFirst like 1,2,3,4,5 OR 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 OR 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 etc.... --->
    ======= Delete all number from reverse and except very next item to middle ====

    <cfset convertToArray = listtoarray(lstFirst)>
    <cfset getRoundValue =round(arraylen(convertToArray)/2)>
    <cfset findMidNextEle = ArraySlice(convertToArray,1,getRoundValue)>

    <cfset LfirstMiddle = listgetat(lstFirst,listfind(lstFirst,listlast(arraytolist(findMidNextEle)))-1)>

    <cfloop from="#listlen(lstFirst)#" to="1" index="i" step="-1">
        <cfset listgetVal = listgetat(lstFirst,i)>
        <cfif LfirstMiddle NEQ listgetVal >
            <cfset lstFirst =listdeleteat(lstFirst,i)>
        </cfif>
        <br/><cfdump var="#lstFirst#" /><br/>
    </cfloop>



    =========== Delete 7,6 and so on or 9,10 and  delete 6,10 without deleting 7 and 9 ================================= <br/>

    <cfset lstMiddleMiddle =  listfind(lstMiddle,listgetat(lstMiddle,listfind(lstMiddle,listlast(mid(lstMiddle,1,listlen(lstMiddle)))))) >

    <cfloop from="1" to="#listlen(lstMiddle)#" index="j">

        <cfset userList = listlen(lstMiddle)>

        <cfif userList GT 3 >
            <cfset lstMiddle1 = listdeleteat(lstMiddle,lstMiddleMiddle-1)>
            <cfset lstMiddle2 = listdeleteat(lstMiddle1,lstMiddleMiddle)>

            <cfset lstMiddleMiddle = listfind(lstMiddle2,listgetat(lstMiddle2,listfind(lstMiddle2,listlast(mid(lstMiddle2,1,listlen(lstMiddle2))))))>
            <cfset lstMiddle = lstMiddle2>
            <br/><cfdump var="#lstMiddle2#" /></br>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset lstMiddle3 = listdeleteat(lstMiddle2,1)>
            <cfset lstMiddle4 = listdeleteat(lstMiddle3,2)>
            <cfbreak/>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
    enter code here
    <cfdump var="#lstMiddle4#" /> <br/>
    =============== Delete from reverse except last number ==========

    <!--- It's will work for all dynamic values --->

    <cfset LastEle = listlast(lstLast)>
    <cfloop from="#listlen(lstLast)#" to="1" step="-1" index="k">
        <cfset getCurrentValue = listgetat(lstLast,k)>

        <cfif LastEle NEQ getCurrentValue>
            <cfset lstLast =listdeleteat(lstLast,k)>
        </cfif>
        </br><cfdump var="#lstLast#" /><br/>
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>**
```

Comment: Welcome to S.O. While answers are always welcome, please consider adding a brief description of how the code resolves the issue.  Explaining "how" the problem was solved is more helpful than just a block of code alone.

Comment: Sure Ageax. I'm the new person to answers stackover flow. I will do it in upcoming answers. Thanks.